# How can I speed up loading thousands of images?

Tags: image, d3.js, loading

I'm using d3 to set thousands of rectangles with different images filled. Here is the code for 'def' part.

`
d3.json("data/data.json", function(error, data){

```
    var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data);                    
    rects.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d,i) {
            return i*barheight ;
        })
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("width", barwidth)
        .attr("height", barheight)
        .attr("fill", function(d){
            return "rgb"+ d.rgb;
        });
```

//change cover image

```
    var def = defsvg.selectAll("def")
                .data(data);

     def.enter()
        .append("pattern")
        .attr("id", function(d){
            return d.name
        })
        .attr("width", 1)
        .attr("height", 1)
        .append("image")
        .attr("width", coverwidth)
        .attr("height", coverheight)
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
            return "img/" + d.name;
        });


    cover.attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", coverwidth)
        .attr("height", coverheight)
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", coverwidth)
        .attr("height", coverheight);

    d3.selectAll("rect")
        .on("click", function(d){
            cover.attr("fill", function(){
                return "url(#" + d.name + ")";
            });
        });
    })
```

`

But the problem is the data is 14000+ . Correspondently, there are 14000 + items in the folder "img". Even though each image is only 30kb, it's still to much for the project, especially when it's launched on mobile device. Is there any solution for it? Thank you!

Comment: If I'm going the math right that's like 420 MB of images loading on a single page? What are the pixel dimension of each image? What does loading 14,000+ of them even look like on screen?

Comment: No, I won't show them together. It will show one image when user click on one rect.

Comment: So you load all the images at page load time with the hopes the user will click 14,000 times?  Have you thought about loading them at "click-time"?  Could you provide enough code to reproduce your issue fully?

Comment: I just add some code, is it clear now?Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely untested but load the image in the `click` event.  Here `defs` is a d3 selection to a `<defs>` node in the SVG.  You don't need to data bind and create all the `pattern` nodes up front.  This should create the pattern, append an image to it, wait for the image to load and then finally fill the rect.

```
d3.selectAll("rect")
  .on("click", function(d) {
    defs.append("pattern")
      .attr("id", d.name)
      .attr("width", 1)
      .attr("height", 1)
      .append("image")
      .attr("onload", function() {
        cover.attr("fill", "url(#" + d.name + ")");
      })
      .attr("width", coverwidth)
      .attr("height", coverheight)
      .attr("xlink:href", "img/" + d.name);
    });
```

Comment: It works really good. Only one thing to say, there is a missing `)`after the `cover.attr` THANK YOU SO MUCH~